How do you align a page grid to text baselines in Inkscape?
When I set my text to 11 points between text baselines and also add an 11 point grid to the page they don't line up. When the text anchor and the first baseline is aligned to the grid further baselines get progressively further below the grid lines.
I could fudge the grid measurements to line up with the text baselines however I'd like to get it exact if I could. Any ideas?
This happens both with flowed and manual return characters.

For the record, I got perfect alignment both with 11pt linespace, and with 1 line spacing and 11pt font (using Inkscape v1.4, Helvetica font on macOS).

It seems to depend on the font.  Not sure why that is. In Windows 11 Inkscape v1.3.2 (latest stable), text set to 11pt Montserrat with 11pt line spacing aligns perfectly to an 11pt grid, but other fonts don't. Not sure if this is an Inkscape font rendering issue, or a problem with certain fonts. Maybe something you could raise with the developers, report as a bug perhaps. In the meantime the only fix I can think of would be to make minute adjustments to the line spacing.

If text handling/accuracy is crucial for something you are creating, might be better to use actual page layout software such as Scribus (or InDesign or similar).   Inkscape has fairly basic text handling and formatting - as it's not really designed with page layout in mind.
